# Timeout on StateT with IO

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, state-monad

I have a custom type

```hs
type GI a = StateT GenState IO a
```

where GenState is a state I keep for Generating Random Trees of some kind.

When generating my trees, termination is not guaranteed in a reasonable amount of time. That's why I thought I might terminate the calculation and restart it over and over again with a timeout until a result is given.

So my question is how to write a function of the form

```hs
tryGeneration :: GI a -> GI a
tryGeneraton action = ...
```

where action is the calculation to try in some microseconds and if it runs out of time begin the action from the start.

Please keep in mind that I'm quite new to Monad Transformers and I cannot say that i fully understand them yet.

I tried to use lift with System.Timeout.timeout and did not succeed

**EDIT**: thank you all for your suggestions. I followed them, and got it done in the IO monad.

```hs
tryGenerationTime :: Int -> GenState -> GI a -> IO (a, GenState)
tryGenerationTime time state action = do
    (_, s') <- -- change the random state to not generate the same thing over and over
    res <- timeout time (runStateT action s') 
    case res of 
        Nothing -> tryGenerationTime time s' action
        Just r  -> return r

timeItT :: Int -> GI a -> GI a
timeItT time action = do
    state <- get
    (x, s') <- lift $ tryGenerationTime time state action
    put s'
    return x
```

Any suggestion to improving this code is welcome. I just wanted to get it done fast, since that wasn't the solution to my generation problem and I needed to set a limit to the tree height to succeed.

Comment: Why does the calculation not terminate in a reasonable amount of time?

Comment: I use randomness to generate the trees and because they need to satisfy some condition, sometimes the subtrees can be huge, requiring a whole lot of time to end. In practice when that happens i just manually terminate the calculation

Comment: I suppose you would have to figure out what to do with the state if the execution times out. It certainly wouldn't use the last state before the timeout because that would be unpredictable (and `timeout` wouldn't know how to do it). Perhaps it resets to the value before the `timeout` command; I assume `StateT` can't do that by itself and you have to write the code for that.

Comment: I would like to keep the state after the command is run. This is because i carry the seed for the randomness and restarting to the previous state would just result in the exact same computation.

Comment: In your case it might make more sense to use `IORef` to hold the state. I don't think StateT can possibly do what you're asking because StateT doesn't know about IO and IO doesn't know about StateT

Comment: Sounds like you could spend some time making sure your condition is met faster than simply generating completely random data until you meet your condition by luck. For example, if you need a tree with at least 30 even numbers, don't just generate random numbers until you get 30 even ones and feel compelled to use the other 10,000 odd numbers you unluckily got. Just pick 30 random even numbers, generate a reasonable number of additional numbers, then build the tree.

Comment: I'm actually trying to generate semantically correct trees for a C-like programming language and feed them to a compiler I'm writing for testing. The branching factor is huge and that's why I cannot figure out a way (if there is one) to make it terminate fast. I also couldn't find anyone having a method online for getting them fast so I'm pretty much trying to make it work alone.

Comment: Consider whether you can write `RandomGen r => r -> IO Tree` - you can use StateT internally to manage the randomgen if you want, but the parameter is pure and you pass a different one on each attempt - there's no need to keep the random sequence alive when it times out - you just start a new random sequence.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what you actually want is more like

```hs
tryGeneration :: GI a -> IO a
tryGeneraton action = ...
```

in such a way that all of your "build a tree" actions have timeout-based retries.

The key thing to understand is that "attempt to do X; if you aren't done in n milliseconds, start over" is IO's job; IO is where you have access to things like time. (Of course there are wrappers you could and should use when you only need part of what IO has to offer.)
This is fine; you have access to `IO` in `GI`, you probably just have to `lift` it.

That said, there's not enough information here to say exactly how to do what you want, and I'm more familiar with free-monad effect systems than mtl transformers anyway...